# Send emails from Firebase without disabling the integrated email service

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase auth to send reset password and account verification emails but I want to add other emails, eg: "welcome to ..." or "Your account was deleted"

I could enable SMTP but this disables the integrated email service. Is there a way to use both at the same time?

Comment: Do you want to change the content of the reset password and account verification emails OR create and send totally different emails?

Comment: I need to send completely different emails. Such as a welcome email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use my own SMTP server, integrated email service is disabled.

I think you may be misunderstanding a part of the documentation there. You can use your own SMTP server to send Firebase's regular emails, in which case indeed the built-in SMTP service won't be used. But if you use your own SMTP server to send other emails, that has nothing to do with Firebase's regular emails and SMTP server.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the emailing function included in the Authentication service for sending other, customized, emails.

For that you will need to use a third-party bulk email services.

The easiest way is to use the [Trigger Email extensions](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email?authuser=0), which offers a lot of flexibility (e.g. the possibility to render emails using Handlebar templates) and is to be used with bulk email service providers, like SendGrid, Mailgun, etc.

---

If you prefer to develop this interface with bulk email services from scratch, you can quite easily do that in a Cloud Function. There is an [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation) in the Cloud Functions Library. Looking at the [code of the Extension](http://bulk%20email%20service) (which is actually based on a Cloud Function) is also very inspiring.

Comment: To use this extension I need to supply SMTP credentials.  If I use my own SMTP server, integrated email service is disabled. That is my question, is there a way to use both at the same time? (SMTP and Integrated email service)

Comment: "If I use my own SMTP server, integrated email service is disabled." I think you may be misunderstanding a part of the documentation there. You can use your own SMTP server to send Firebase's regular emails, in which case indeed the built-in SMTP service won't be used. But if you use your own SMTP server to send other emails, that has nothing to do with Firebase's regular emails and SMTP server.